# Trying to understanding how VUs works k6

Tags: performance, testing, k6

As shown in the image I ran only 2 VUs but it returned “100” complete. What would that 100 be? Number of scripts run or vus? So for every 1 VU I have 50 scripts running, is that it?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUquH.png

Answer (score 3):

You have configured k6 to run with 2 vus for 2 minutes `--vus 2 --duration 2m`.

You can see this in the "summary" as "2 looping VUs for 2m0s".

This means that you are running the [constant-vus](https://k6.io/docs/using-k6/scenarios/executors/constant-vus) executor, the options you provided are just a shortcut for it. Arguably the "looping vus" description explains better that you have 2 VUs looping for 2 minutes.

As you can see above you also do 100 iterations- executions of the default function. And those take around 2.42s and 2min = 120s / 2.42 = 49.5. But k6 will try to finish started execution for a time (gracefulStop as mentioned in the screenshot), so it will make around 50 iterations per VU.

If you just want to do 2 iterations - add `--iterations 2` or use [shared-iterations](https://k6.io/docs/using-k6/scenarios/executors/shared-iterations)  executor directly, those options are the shortcut for it basically.

Comment: so basically interaction is the script that i want to run more than once right, example, if i want to run 1k script so that i'm saying that i make 1k interactions not vus.

Comment: First it's `iteration` not `interaction` which ... sounds more like .. anything, including a single request for example.

If you want to make exactly X iterations - you should configure X iterations, and then you can have up to that many VUs runnign them.

Comment: so for example a i want to run 20K of the same script in this example a put it on the 20K in iteration or VUs?

Comment: In your case where you are using `shared-iterations` executor - yes. In others you need to look at the documentation per each and see what you need. 

For example in `per-vu-iterations` you need `iterations`*`vus` to be equal to the number you want. As `itearations` there means "iteration per vu" while in `shared-iterations`, `itearations` is the total number of iterations. 

For some that isn't even possible - `contant-vus` only can be configured how long to run and with how many VUs - the number iterations comes from how many it manages to complete given those restrictions.

Comment: @Massallys if you think this is correct answer - you can mark it as such ;)

Answer (score -2):

> As shown in the image I ran only 2 VUs but it returned “100” complete.
> What would that 100 be? Number of scripts run or vus? So for every 1
> VU I have 50 scripts running, is that it?

Restart.

-> sudo apt-get update
-> sudo apt-get upgrade

if not, download it again with root manager
end
cp

Comment: I'm on windows and even with npm npx or choco didn't it works

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Everything works as expected. What would an update improve? Why would it help?